# Most optimized way of extracting data from planet.osm

Tags: openstreetmap, osmosis

I want to cut extracts from planet.osm.bz2 .
I have found this command

```
bzcat downloaded.osm.bz2 | osmosis  --read-xml enableDateParsing=no file=-  --bounding-box top=49.5138 left=10.9351 bottom=49.3866 right=11.201 --write-xml file=- | bzip2 > extracted.osm.bz2
```

Only concern I have the disc space. planet.osm uncompressed is 400GB!

How much space would use this command from WIKI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way is to use the planet.osm.pbf dump, which is a binary format and substantially faster than bzipped XML.

You should also use [Osmconvert](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert) instead of osmosis for a task like this.

A suitable command would be

```
osmconvert planet-latest.osm.pbf -b=10.5,49,11.5,50 -o=nuernberg.osm.pbf
```

This will create a PBF file, which is quicker to process than bzipped XML. Another way to speed the process up is to start with an [extract from geofabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/) that contains the area you need. If you're only after a city, downloading the Country or State extract for the region is faster than downloading the planet file.

Comment: Does pbf format keep all data that exists in osm.bz2? Especially amenities... ???

Comment: PBF is just a binary representation of OSM data, like OSM XML is. They both contain the same data. Within that data are the key=value pairs that make up tags.

Comment: I can't get it to work with history files.

Answer (score 0):

The [gosmparse](https://github.com/thomersch/gosmparse) library by [@thomesch](https://github.com/thomersch) is phenominal.

It's written in Go and it's about as fast as it's likely to get. It's a phenomenal library.

You can run it against the `planet.osm.pbf` variant of OSM, so the overall footprint is far less than 400Gb. (It's about 60Gb at the time of writing.)